# How to deploy an app on every branch push using Docker, AWS ECS, CircleCI and Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, circleci

I have a standalone Django app docker image which gets deployed to AWS ECS whenever a push event gets triggered on the corresponding repository using a CI. The container runs on FARGATE and also has a public IP assigned to it.

**The problems**

Problem 1: I want the containers to auto destroy themselves if there was no request in last 10 mins apart from health check.

Problem 2: I want to dynamically create subdomains in Route53(public zone) and link it with the instance.

Has anyone worked on something like this?

Comment: Are you sure about requirement #1? This is normally done by some operator or scaling function in the control-plane, rather than the container itself. Problem #2 is solved with elastic-ips.

Comment: These should be asked as separate questions, api calls or cloudformation is what you want. Triggers for a push to any branch.

Comment: The overall problem is to setup an auto deploy on any branch with a unique URL posted back to the pull request.

Comment: Are you using github, bitbucket or gitlab ?

Comment: I am using Github